# Subtract month from 'yyyymm' in js

Tags: javascript, sql, date

How do I subtract a month from a date in this format using a Javascript function?

> For example: 
>       201301 -> 201212

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function subtractMonth(year_month){
year_month = parseInt(year_month);
if(year_month%100 == 1) return year_month-89;
return year_month-1;
}
```

Comment: Based on the subject I think the year month is in string format.

Comment: @Hogan it shouldn't matter. JavaScript will attempt to box the `month` parameter

Comment: @Hogan I’ve added the line `month = parseInt(month);` which should convert the string to a number.

Comment: Cool, but a better name for *month* is *value* as it doesn't represent a month.

Comment: This function takes a string parameter and returns an integer?

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
function processDate(dateString){
    var month=dateString%100;
    var year=dateString/100;
    var d=new Date(year,month-1,1,0,0,0,0)

    d.setDate(d.getDate()-2);
    year=d.getFullYear().toString();
    month=("0"+(d.getMonth()+1).toString()).substr(-2);
    document.write(year+month);
}
```

`processDate(201401)` should give you `201312`